# Probability Distribution of simple linear regression outcomes

Tags: probability, regression

I'm going to predict the random variable $Y_i$ by linear regression: $Y_i=\alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon$.

Assuming that the dependent variable ($Y_i$) has a normal distribution with different means and the same variance, i.e., $Y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$, can anybody explain the distribution of the estimated variable ($y$)?

Can I assume it(estimated variable by regression) as a normal distribution? Can I get the variance of this estimation?

UPDATE: ${X_i}$  is a sequence of observations, which I am assuming are drawn independently from a Normal latent variable, Y.

Comment: Do $X_i$'s have Normal dist. or $Y_i$'s?

Comment: @Arash Only $Y_i$ . $X_i$ is a deterministic variable.

Comment: I suppose $\{X_i\}$ is a sequence of observations, which you are assuming they are drawn independently from a Normal latent variable, $Y$, right?

Comment: OK, I seem your definition of the problem is right.

Comment: I suggest that you revise and clarify the question, so you get better answers. Cheers :)